# Creating ng-grids dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have a problem creating ng-grids dynamically:
The next function loops through each element of $scope.dataSparqlResponses (each element is an array of data) and put the value of the iteration in $scope.dataSparqlAux. And **$scope.dataSparqlAux** is the variable used in the grids (data input). The problem is that in each iteration this variable ($scope.dataSparqlAux) is reassigned, so in the template I can only see the **last grid with data**.

```
**controller.js**
$scope.crearGrids = function() {           
    angular.forEach($scope.dataSparqlResponses, function(elem) {
        $scope.dataSparqlAux = elem.data;
        $scope.dataGrids.push({grid: {
                data: 'dataSparqlAux', 
                enablePinning: false,
                showFooter: true,
                selectedItems: [],
                i18n: 'es',
                showSelectionCheckbox: true,
                afterSelectionChange: function() {
                    console.log(this);
                },
                columnDefs: [{field: elem.nombre + '.value', displayName: elem.nombre, cellTemplate: templateWithTooltip}]
            }});
        console.log($scope.dataGrids);

    });

};

**template.html**
<div data-get-width data-num-elementos="{{dataGrids.length}}" >
      <div ng-repeat="dataGrid in dataGrids">
            <div class="tabla_det" ng-grid="dataGrid.grid"></div>                        
      </div>
</div>
```

is possible to do something like this?

```
$scope.dataGrids.push({grid: {
        **data: 'dataSparqlResponses[cont]',** 
        enablePinning: false,
        showFooter: true,
        selectedItems: [],
        i18n: 'es',
        showSelectionCheckbox: true,
        afterSelectionChange: function() {
                console.log(this);
        },
        columnDefs: [{field: elem.nombre + '.value', displayName: elem.nombre, cellTemplate: templateWithTooltip}]
}});
console.log($scope.dataGrids);
```

How can I fix this to create grids and display information dynamically?

Regards and thanks for your time.

EDIT: here a plunker with the problem http://plnkr.co/edit/zYtuMW4TKW053YoDY0kg?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've shared an answer on [github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1294#issuecomment-49156134) about your issue.

Basically, data is referencing a variable, you're not storing it.
What you can do is reference a new variable on every loop, as shown in the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yixom/5/watch?js,output).

Declare an index :

```
var index = 0;
```

You declare your string with the index of the sub-document :

```
var dirtyConcat = 'dataSparqlResponses['+index+'].data';
```

Don't forget to increment the index :

```
++index;
```

Then, you reference it.

```
data: dirtyConcat,
```

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect. I'm new with javascript and Angularjs. And with this solution, I can follow with my project. Thanks again.